# Runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int'

Tags: c++, algorithm, rte

I am solving the [House Robber](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/) problem on Leetcode and I am getting a "Runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int'". Why is this error occuring?

My code:

```
  class Solution {
  public:
    int rob(vector<int>& a) {
        int n=a.size();
        vector<int> dp(n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            dp.push_back(0);
        dp[0]=a[0]; dp[1]=a[1];
        int ans=0;
        for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
        {
            dp[i]+=dp[i-2]+a[i];
            ans=max(ans,dp[i]);
        }
            
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be wary of the input size. With `dp[0]=a[0]; dp[1]=a[1];`, you assume that the input at least has a size of 2.

Is this the case? Then it's fine, otherwise the program would crash as you described.

Usually with these `Leetcode` problems is that you need to take care of *all* corner cases. Maybe your solution works for the general case, but you should also take annoying input into consideration (empty lists, lists with one element, etc,...)

Comment: But codeforces or other platforms doesn't do this right? Is this a leetcode exclusive thing?

Comment: @AdityaKarad, I don't know about the other platforms. Leetcode does it (speaking from experience). But it makes sense that they do - you solution should be robust to all inputs.

Comment: The constraint in the problem says `0 <= nums.length <= 100`, so you can for sure get input lists with zero element. Then you have a problem.

Comment: @AdityaKarad *But codeforces or other platforms doesn't do this right* -- It has nothing to do with other platforms.  Accessing element out-of-bounds in C++ leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

Null pointer set aside, you can solve this problem with a more efficient algorithm, without using a `dp` array (in constant memory):

```
class Solution {
public: 
    int rob(const std::vector<int>& nums) {
        int length = nums.size();
        if (length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int prev = 0;
        int curr = 0;
        int temp;
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            temp = std::max(curr, prev + nums[index]);
            prev = curr;
            curr = temp;
        }

        return curr;
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, tips, efficient algorithms with a variety of languages, and time/space complexity analysis in there.